# I want update object document fields into an array in MongoDB database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I am new to MongoDB trying to update an object field into an array in multiple documents in MongoDB.

Below I have mentioned my previous model and the new model also. I already updated the schema but I need to update previous data to the new format.

This is the current document structure:

```
[
{
  "id": "1",
  "location": {
    "type": "point",
    "coordinates": {
      "x": 20.291464,
      "y": 85.8560129
    }
  }
},
{
  "id": "2",
  "location": {
    "type": "point",
    "coordinates": {
      "x": 20.291464,
      "y": 85.8560129
    }
  }
},
{
  "id": "3",
  "location": {
    "type": "point",
    "coordinates": {
      "x": 20.291464,
      "y": 85.8560129
    }
  }
}
]
```

This is the desired structure:

```
[{
  "id": "1",
  "location": {
    "type": "point",
    "coordinates": [
      20.291464,
      85.8560129
    ]
  }
},
{
  "id": "2",
  "location": {
    "type": "point",
    "coordinates": [
      20.291464,
      85.8560129
    ]
  }
},
{
  "id": "3",
  "location": {
    "type": "point",
    "coordinates": [
      20.291464,
      85.8560129
    ]
  }
}]
```

Comment: Please be aware, coordinates in MongoDB, i.e [GeoJSON Objects](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/geojson/) have format `[ lon, lat ]`. In case these coordinates are in India, it would be the other way around: `coordinates": [ 85.8560129, 20.291464 ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do a `$set` or `$addFields` in an aggregation pipeline and create the array with x,y field values.

```js
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "location.coordinates": [
        "$location.coordinates.x",
        "$location.coordinates.y"
      ]
    }
  }
],
{ multi: true }
)
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yYi6j-TtOTI)